# Importing Appliances (Hortanworks Sandbox) into Virtual box showing up ERROR: Callee RC: NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED (0x800706BE)

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, sandbox, hortonworks-sandbox

Trying to import Hortonworks Sand box into my virtual box on Mac machine. Upon importing I am getting  Callee RC:  NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED (0x800706BE) error message do know how to resolve this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my research on this issue I found the following

1. All these OVA files are huge in size and some times they might not get downloaded completely 
   So always run the check sum for the file you have downloaded and compare the value with the original, If both are same then your file is not corrupted

On Mac>> Open Terminal >>

SXXXXXX:~ vmalladi$ md5 /Users/vmalladi/Downloads/HDP_2.3.2_virtualbox.ovf

MD5 (/Users/vmalladi/Downloads/HDP_2.3.2_virtualbox.ovf) = 95a7db58e609e0e016ea6130962fdfb0

The problem was resolved for me after I download (I used LAN cable to avoid network interruptions)the file completely